# How do automatically adjust the textarea's height in flex when I give it some default value

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

When the parent component is loaded, I give textarea a default value, and I want to the textarea automatically adjust it's height with the value. The code is followed:

```
protected function commentContentGroup_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                userCommentContent.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, sendInfor);
                scrollerContentHieght=20;
                commentContentGroupHeight=this.height;
                userCommentContent.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, userCommentContent_textInputHandler);
                userCommentContent.addEventListener(TextOperationEvent.CHANGE, userCommentContent_changeHandler);
//              userCommentContent.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT,userCommentContent_changeHandler);
                this.userCommentContent.text = "The Object that defines the event listener that handles the event. For example, if you use myButton.addEventListener() to register an event listener, myButton is the value of the currentTarget";

            }
```

I think the CHANGE event is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign height every time the component is displayed (added to display list) then you can use `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE`. If you want it only once then creation complete should be sufficient. If you need more help please paste your complete code.